# Put the first row as the column names of my dataframe with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my dataframe:

```
x<-data.frame(A = c(letters[1:10]), M1 = c(11:20), M2 = c(31:40), M3 = c(41:50))

colnames(x)<-NULL
```

I want to tranpose (`t(x)`) and consider the first column of x as the colnames of the new dataframe `t(x)`.

Also I need them (the colnames of `t(x)`) to be identified as words/letters (as character right?)

Is it possible to do this with dplyr package?

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x <- data.frame(
  A = c(letters[1:10]),
  M1 = c(11:20),
  M2 = c(31:40),
  M3 = c(41:50))

x %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = value, 2:ncol(x)) %>% 
  spread(key = names(x)[1], value = "value")
  key  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
1  M1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
2  M2 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
3  M3 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

Answer (score 14):

The {janitor} package is good for this and is flexible enough to be able to select any row to push to column names:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

x <- x %>% row_to_names(row_number = 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily in base R. Just make the first column of x be the row names, then remove the first column and transpose.

```
row.names(x) = x[,1]
x = t(x[,-1])
x
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
M1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
M2 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
M3 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `column_to_rownames` from the `tibble` package would be your simplest solution. Use it before you transpose with `t`.

```
library(magrittr)
library(tibble)

x %>% 
  column_to_rownames("A") %>% 
  t

#>     a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
#> M1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#> M2 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
#> M3 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

The "M1", "M2", "M3" above are row names. If you want to keep them inside (as a column), you can add `rownames_to_column` from the same package.

```
x %>% 
  column_to_rownames("A") %>% 
  t %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  rownames_to_column("key")

#>   key  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
#> 1  M1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#> 2  M2 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
#> 3  M3 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

Essentially, 

`column_to_rownames("A")` converts column "A" in `x` to row names,

`t` transposes the data.frame (now a matrix),

`as.data.frame` reclassifies it back as a data.frame (which is necessary for the next function), and

`rownames_to_column("key")` converts the row names into a new column called "key".

Answer (score 1):

Using `rownames_to_column()` from the `tibble` package

```r
library(magrittr)
library(tibble)

x %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  `colnames<-`(.[1,]) %>%
  .[-1,] %>%
  `rownames<-`(NULL)
#>    A  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
#> 1 M1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#> 2 M2 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
#> 3 M3 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50

x %>% 
  `row.names<-`(.[, 1]) %>% 
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  .[-1,] 
#>     a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
#> M1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#> M2 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
#> M3 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: I wish slice worked here to keep it in tidyverse. It does for the second chain, but not the first. ` df %>% 
      colnames<-(.[1,]) %>% # cannot change this to slice
      slice(-1)  #remove the first row`